# Reputation change indicator on tab and next to overall reputation off by 1?

Tags: bug, reputation, user-interface

I received `+2` reputation from an [approved edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10367116).
However when I visited my profile page it showed only a change of `1`. See screen shot below:

[image: profile page with reputation change indicator showing 1]

I'm not sure how I can try to reproduce this bug, though.

Comment: Did you already try to [blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)?

Comment: Did you downvote an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had previously downvoted an answer, and that answer has now been removed, so you get the 1 reputation back from the downvote, but the *removal* doesn't get calculated into the reputation change. So there was a change of -1 that you probably never cleared as it doesn't give you notifications of negative changes, then you had a change of +2 for the edit, which put your change at +1 and is now displayed, then that post was removed restoring your reputation but not changing the indicator.

Make sure the box next to "show removed posts" is checked at the bottom of your reputation history.